# django count distinct max

Tags: python, django, postgresql, psql

Sorry that I can't provide my entire code as its for my work and I am currently using my personal laptop.

I am new to django and need a help to solve this

I need to get the result of distinct count max

so,
I have Content and Comment tables
Content has content_id and title
Comment has comment_id, comment, content_id(FK)

every time when users comment on content comment table will record these.
eg.
Comment

```
comment_id    comment    content_id
1             blah blah  1
2             blah blah  1
3             blah blah  2
4             blah blah  3
```

I need to get the content title which has the most number of comments on in.
so for the example above,
content_id 1 has the most comments as it has 2 comments.
I need to get the title of content_id 1 from table Content.

in SQL I can use something like (not exactly, but just to give you the idea of what I want to get)

```
SELECT DISTINCT(content.content_id) AS no_of_comments,
       title
FROM content INNER JOIN comment
ON content.content_id = comment.content_id
GROUP BY content.content_id
ORDER BY no_of_comments DESC
```

then I can get

```
no_of_comments    title
2                 Title Of Content One
1                 Title Of Content Two
1                 Title Of Content Three
```

then I just need to return 'Title Of Content One' as a result of my code

I know how to get these from SQL, starting from the code above but have no idea how I can do this with django

I think I might need to use cursor stuff in django if it has, 
but as I started from joining these two tables, I am not sure what to do.
And I am using django 1.6

Please help me.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset

Comment: Thx, @Anentropic this page helped a lot but still have a question.  `c = Comment.objects.values('content_id').annotate(count=Count('conent_id')).order_by('-count')` and then 
`c[0].count` 
would this get the maximum number of count? if so, then how can I get the title? or at least the content_id?

Comment: it would make more sense to query from the perspective of the content model: `Content.objects.annotate(count=Count('comment__id')).order_by('-count')`

Comment: @Anentropic ah got it! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you want with this query:

```
Content.objects.annotate(count=Count('comment__id')).order_by('-count')
```

there is no need for the `GROUP BY`